# Настройка Python на Sublime text3

Tags: python, sublime-text, текст

Все установочные сделала, компилятор прописала:

```
"cmd": ["python3", "-i", "-u", "$file"],
"file_regex": "^[ ]File \"(...?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
"selector": "source.python"
```

Теперь проблема с `Tools->SublimeREPL->Python->Python`
пишет не удается найти файл, через <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> тоже пишет:

> [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл

Что делать? Как РЕПЛ настроить?

Answer (score 1):

1. Открываем Sublime Text -> Tools -> Build System -> New Build System
2. Вставляем в открывшийся файл следующие строки, чтобы получилось вот так:

   ```
   {
       "cmd": ["python3", "-i", "-u", "$file"],
       "file_regex": "^[ ]File \"(...?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
       "selector": "source.python"
   }
   ```
3. Сохраняем файл с названием python3.sublime-build и не меняем путь предложенный редактором
4. Идем и ставим галочку Tools -> Build system -> python3

Если вам не требуется передавать через консоль в программу аргументы (например input()), то вы уже можете проверить
работу создав и сохранив (без сохранения будет ошибка) тестовый файл, а затем нажав Ctrl+B. Снизу 
появится консоль с выводом результата.

Для проверки предлагаю выполнить следующий код:

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

-----Делаем интерактивную консоль-----

5. Заходим на сайт https://packagecontrol.io/installation и копируем содержимое бокса Sublime Text 3 в буфер обмена.
6. Открываем Sublime Text -> View -> Show Console и вставляем содержимое буфера обмена, затем жмем Enter. Если у вас 
   ничего не произошло, то выполните ручную установку описанную на сайте из пункта 5.
7. Жмем Ctrl+Shift+P -> пишем Install Package -> пишем sublimeREPL и устанавливаем.
8. Поскольку в sublimeREPL установлен python 2, то идем в Sublime Text -> Preferences -> Browse Packages
9. Открываем в текстовом редакторе файл SublimeREPL -> config -> Python -> Main.sublime-menu
10. Находим внутри этого файла столбик с аргументами children -> args -> cmd и меняем значение "python" на "python3". 
    Сохраняем и закрываем файл.
11. Открываем тестовый python-файл (например из пункта 4)
12. Открываем консоль редактора как в пункте 6 и пишем sublime.log_commands(True)
13. Sublime Text -> Tools -> sublimeREPL -> Python -> Python RUN current file и затем копируем из консоли строку repl_open 
    целиком со всеми аргументами.
14. В консоли пишем sublime.log_commands(False)
15. Sublime Text -> Preferences -> Key Bindings. Забиндим хоткей для быстрого исполнения файла в интерактивной консоли REPL
16. Вставьте в User-конфиг (он пустой) следующий код (ключ keys сделайте свой по желанию, в "сommand" пишите "repl_open", а 
    в "args" закидываете все атрибуты которые скопировали из консоли. Их не обязательно так разбивать по строкам, можно все 
    в одну оставить:

    ```
      [    { "keys": ["ctrl+b"], 
                  "command": "repl_open", 
                  "args": {"cmd": ["python", "-i", "-u", "$file_basename"], 
                           "cwd": "$file_path", 
                           "encoding": "utf8", 
                           "extend_env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"}, 
                           "external_id": "python", 
                           "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage", 
                           "type": "subprocess"} },
        ]
    ```

    17. Сохраняем файл, перезапускаем Sublime Text и используем заданный хоткей.

Comment: В режиме редактирования нажмите Enter перед пунктом 5. Тогда каждый пункт списка будет нормально отображаться.

Comment: Спасибо большое что расписали как делать дальше. До пункта 10 все сделала) Теперь вопрос по пункту 10: 
                        "encoding": "utf8",
                        "cmd": ["python3", "-i", "-u"],  # вот здесь я 3 добавила, а в синстаксисе нужно?
                        "cwd": "$file_path",
                        "syntax": "Packages/PythonВОТ ТУТ?/Python И ТУТ?.tmLanguage",

Comment: Я что то не то меняю, в Main.sublime-menu путаюсь куда, очень много где это написано CMD CHILDREN ARGS, потому что дальше пробую через консоль когда Sublime Text -> Tools -> sublimeREPL -> Python -> Python RUN current file пишет нету файла

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Av_m_kbnzuY&index=18&list=UUD5_waDcGBhof9xuA1qovTQ